# Включить GIF во время выполнения кода WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Уверен, что ответ прост, но все же. Есть код:

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox_loader.Show();

    login.Text = (Authorization.Auth()) ? "Успех" : "Провал";

    pictureBox_loader.Hide();
}
```

Суть в том, что картинка (это гифка) подвисает во время выполнения авторизации, оно в целом логично, т.к. поток занят. Как мне запустить гифку в другом потоке, чтобы она анимировалась пока выполняется код авторизации?

Запуск авторизации в отдельном потоке (гифка все равно виснет):

```
private void authThread()
{
    this.login.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
        login.Text = (Authorization.Auth()) ? "Успех" : "Провал";
        pictureBox_loader.Hide();
    }));
}
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox_loader.Show();
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(authThread)).Start();
}
```

Comment: А может в потоке запускать код авторизации а не гифку?

Comment: Попробовал и так, все равно гифка виснет.

Comment: Показывайте код, как вы запускаете авторизацию в отдельном потоке

Comment: Обновил пост...

Comment: Насколько я помню, ```this.login.BeginInvoke``` - это запуск кода в UI потоке. И вы запускаете это из UI потока. То есть оно все в одном потоке выполняется, вот и тормозит.

Comment: А как надо сделать тогда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет смысла в отдельном потоке просто запускать задачу на UI поток. Попробуйте для начала выполнить аутентификацию, потом запускать задачу.

```
private void authThread()
{
    var auth = Authorization.Auth(); // это в отдельном потоке
    this.login.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
        login.Text = auth ? "Успех" : "Провал"; // это уже в UI
        pictureBox_loader.Hide();
    }));
}
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox_loader.Show();
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(authThread)).Start();
}
```

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. Спасибо.